# Can't fetch XML response in PHP

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter, bigbluebutton

This is my code to fetch api

```
 $apiurl = "https://class.cvcngr.in/bigbluebutton/api/create?allowStartStopRecording=true&attendeePW=ap&autoStartRecording=false&meetingID=random-1495797&moderatorPW=mp&name=random-1495797&record=false&voiceBridge=74999&welcome=%3Cbr%3EWelcome+to+%3Cb%3E%25%25CONFNAME%25%25%3C%2Fb%3E%21&checksum=ad1f82091f78ee18673f9c5be36df9eef7860187";


  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiurl);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);   
  $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
  echo $xml;
```

In the above, I have used an apiurl which stores URL of API. this is my custom API and there is a test API provided by the service provider

```
$apiurl2 "http://test-install.blindsidenetworks.com/bigbluebutton/api/create?allowStartStopRecording=true&attendeePW=ap&autoStartRecording=false&meetingID=random-9370670&moderatorPW=mp&name=random-9370670&record=false&voiceBridge=79891&welcome=%3Cbr%3EWelcome+to+%3Cb%3E%25%25CONFNAME%25%25%3C%2Fb%3E%21&checksum=0aae50d2d079fd67138a7b266837f6b0112166b5";
```

Bothe the URL gives the same response but I can get data only when I use apiurl2. when I use the first one there is no response. but when I use in the browser directly there is no issues

Comment: it works, you just put the `die;` prematurely that's why you don't see anything. https://www.tehplayground.com/jPcHQojoQUSWWkrv here, it even works on a sanbox

Comment: sorry that code was there by mistake... i have used it to print and see the out... error occurs the same... it works fine for apiurl2

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine, the `$xml` variable is a [SimpleXMLElement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) instance. `echo` tries to print a string. You can print all of its contents with `var_dump($xml)` and access its elements directly with an object operator: `echo $xml->dialNumber` and even loop thru them:

```
<?php

  $apiurl = "https://class.cvcngr.in/bigbluebutton/api/create?allowStartStopRecording=true&attendeePW=ap&autoStartRecording=false&meetingID=random-1495797&moderatorPW=mp&name=random-1495797&record=false&voiceBridge=74999&welcome=%3Cbr%3EWelcome+to+%3Cb%3E%25%25CONFNAME%25%25%3C%2Fb%3E%21&checksum=ad1f82091f78ee18673f9c5be36df9eef7860187";


  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiurl);

  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  $xml      = simplexml_load_string($response);

  // var_dump($xml);
  // echo 'Dial number: ' . $xml->dialNumber;

  foreach ($xml as $key => $value) {
      echo "{$key}: {$value}\n";
  }

  curl_close($ch);
```